# Vue app not working day after working normaly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

So, the problem is that my Vue app was working just fine last night, i turned of the server and went to sleep, nothing was changed or updated and i woke up this morning wanted to continue what i was doing and go for the yarn serve to open it up, and i got the error : "'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". Anyone encountered something similar?

Thanks for answering!
The package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rails-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

So instinctively i tried reinstaling the vue cli, and i done that and again it gives me the same error, so im locked in place rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions step by step:

1. Open cmd and run the command `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`
2. then `npm install -g @vue/cli`
3. Open your project and remove *node_modules*.
4. Re-install the packages.

This must fix your problem.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the help. You know maybe what is causing the error? I've done something with react, node, nest and more and never got the error.

Comment: Can be caused because of several issues. Can't exactly tell the main reason.